# How to describe collective spin measurement in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, measurement-problem, quantum-measurements

What is the QM description for measuring the collective magnetisation of an abitrary number $N$ of protons?

For example, say that the density matrix is separable (no initial entanglement between particles), and each particle $i$ has an arbitrary pure quantum state $a_i|{\uparrow}⟩+b_i|{\downarrow}⟩$. How would I write a measurement operator for the mean spin, or calculate the new state of the system after measuring a particular value?

For reference, I'm intending an apparatus like either Stern-Gerlach (a field gradient which imparts linear momentum dependent on the sum of dipole moments) or else an MRI/NMR receiver coil (where an induced external current depends on the size and orientation of the net magnetic dipole). The protons may be embedded in a macroscopic piece of rigid lattice with no additional magnetisation. I'm guessing the interaction may be too weak to collapse every proton individually into a spin eigenstate, but may cause some entanglement. (I'm interested in the transition between quantum and classical measurements, as $N$ grows.)